# How to rewrite any page to index page with requested URL as $_GET parameter

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Something similar had been discussed here, but this is slight different.

How to tell .htaccess to rewrite any requested page (regardless of it's depth from the site root) with site's index page, but with requested URL as a $_GET parameter, so it can be further handled by php, depending on it's contents, or depending on URL itself.

I was trying something like

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?page=$1
```

but obviously I do something wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What URLs did you test to determine that it is not working and what was the result? What else is in your .htaccess file?

Comment: @UlrichPalha I tested it on root level and on one level below, both with URL's ending with / (pointing to index.php files), and on URL's ending with somefile.php. There is nothing else in .htaccess, just ErrorDocument 404 /404.php, but that shouldn't affect it.

Comment: Your rule looks fine except for the adding the `[L,QSA]` flags as the answer below has i.e. `RewriteRule (.*) index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]` should work

Comment: Unfortunately not, it still throws 500 Internal Server Error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try working on your RegEx. Maybe something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)([\/]*)$ index.php?page=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Comment: Obviously I could use help with my RegEx skills too. Thanks Bill! Love this site!

Comment: Thanks, it works, at least for one level down. I'll figure out the regex to make it work for other levels.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can generate the rewrite code using an online tool like http://www.webtoolhub.com/tn561403-htaccess-url-rewrite.aspx by entering the desired parameters. Just put the url structure and it will write the .htaccess code that you can use or modify according to your needs.